# jQuery Slide Out tab overlaps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery plugin from http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html, but the problem is I have few icons on the page that are overlapping with the jQuery slider when it is clicked. The tabs slide's out perfectly but then it overlaps the content on the page. Does anyone know how to fix the overlapping issue?

Comment: Please provide either a screenshot of the problem, your html/css/javascript or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set z-index for the tab? May set it around 1000, So it wont get overlaped

Comment: Then make the answer as answered,

Comment: @Vijay you cannot accept an answer that soon, You'll get your rep eventually ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either move the slider up in the dom tree as the items are rendered topdown assuming you do not have a `z-index` set on any elements that may overlap, or set a `z-index` that is higher than any elements that may overlap it on the slider.